# Difficulty in understanding variable assignment and function signature output

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Apologies for not being able to word the title better. I'm open to suggestions.

I'm trying to make an inverted index where for each word I'm trying to produce a list of articles that mentions this word. Here's my code below:

```
def makeInvertedIndex(words: List[String], rdd: RDD[Article]): RDD[(String, Iterable[Article])] = {
  val foo = rdd flatMap { article =>
    words.map { lang =>
      (word, article)
    }.filter(pair => pair._2.mentionsWord(pair._1))
  }
  foo.groupByKey
}
```

The function above returns a type of `RDD[(String, Iterable[Article])]` as expected, but if I were to rewrite the function as below:

```
  def makeInvertedIndex(words: List[String], rdd: RDD[Article]): RDD[(String, Iterable[Article])] = {
    rdd flatMap { article =>
      words.map { lang =>
        (word, article)
      }.filter(pair => pair._2.mentionsWord(pair._1))
    }.groupByKey
  }
```

I get an error where the signatures don't match. Is there something I'm missing here?

I would assume that the output types would be the same by first glance. Perhaps the `.groupByKey` in the bottom version is being applied as part of the flatMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rdd flatMap { ... }.groupByKey
```

is parsed as

```
rdd.flatMap({...}.groupByKey)
```

but you want

```
rdd.flatMap({...}).groupByKey
```

This is expected behavior: you want this when you do, say

```
1 + something.foo
```

but it gets a bit hard to follow when `something` is a large expression, like here.

I like to write

```
rdd.flatMap { ... }.groupByKey
```

which will work, but, in this case, I'd rather use a `for`:

```
(for {
   article <- rdd
   word <- words
   if article.mentionsWord(word)
 } yield (word, article)
).groupByKey
```